# How to extract multiple string values from a sentence using regex?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have multiple lines of text in a following format .

Hello {user}, you have been awarded {x} points for being active for more than {y} days.

How do I extract these specific variables using Regex?

e.g. -

Hello **john**, you have been awarded **10** points for being active for more than **2** days.

Upon extracting, I should get john (user), 10 (x) and 2 (y) from above line.

p.s. - I am using java and I need to get it done using regex.

Comment: Are you bound to using regex? I can do it w/o it and get the data you want from it.

Comment: `Hello ([^,]+)` - The first group contains the name. Do the same for others. If you have control on creating the string, I wouldn't recommend using regex.

Comment: `Hello (\\w+), you have been awarded (\\d+) points for being active for more than (\\d+) days` should do

Comment: @MarounMaroun : Well, I have many of such string formats  and many strings. So I find regex is the only generalized approach to extract groups from these. Otherwise my logic would change per every format.

Comment: `"I have many such string formats"` - what does this mean? Give an example of one of the "other" formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go with the following regex:

```
/Hello (\w+), you have been awarded (\d+) points? for being active for more than (\d+) days?\./
```

Do note that I included questions marks after the plural form of "points" and "days", just in case they happen to be singular.

I am also assuming that the username is comprised of word characters only; if not, the `\w+` should be updated accordingly.